# Field Service Management Solution (FSM) for very individual business requirements

Tags: maps, cloud-service, mobile, scheduling, workflow

For our customer service department, I'm looking for a **field service management solution**, which can be **individually adapted to our dedicated business processes and requirements** (and they are really very special, believe me ;-).

Basically, the required solution must support:

- Web UI for order entry, management and validation
- Map UI for visualization of onsite locations
- Interactive scheduling board for workforce management
- Mobile app support for iOS and Android devices
- Cloud-based with REST API interface
- German and English language support
- Customizing features to implement a custom data model, user interface and workflows

A perfect solution would offer powerful **customizing features**, so that we can make individual UI and workflow adjustments without leaving the standard implementation of the software (e.g. like a low code platform). This is important for us, as we still want to receive software updates in the future.

Can anyone recommend such a **workforce management / field service tool**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried [ENGINE4.SERVICE](https://service.engine4.io) by [Mobile Function](https://www.mobile-function.com/)?

They offer a free 30-day trial account. Their tool is very powerful and can be adapted to custom requirements. [ENGINE4.SERVICE](https://service.engine4.io) is a fully featured Field Service Management Solution and based on their universal Low Code Platform [ENGINE4.YOU](https://you.engine4.io). So, it is customizable "by design".

We use [ENGINE4.SERVICE](https://service.engine4.io) for years and are very happy with it. Btw, their customer support team is very fast and helpful as well.